# Laravel - How in "whereHas" check all record in relationship?

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I have 2 models: Customer, Subscription.

Relation in model Customer:

```
    public function subscriptions()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Subscription')
        ->withPivot('subscription_id', 'delivery_type')
        ->orderBy('end_date', 'DESC');
}
```

Confused in my problem: When selecting clients, I need to select only those who have all subscriptions expired ('end_date', '<=', Carbon::today()) and clients without subscriptions.

My query:

```
    public function customers_without_subscriptions()
{
    $customers = Customer::
        doesntHave('subscriptions')
        ->orWhereHas('subscriptions', function (Builder $query) {
            $query->where('end_date', '<=', Carbon::today());
            })
        ->orderBy('name', 'ASC')
        ->paginate(12);
```

Now all clients are selected who have at least 1 expired subscription - This is not correct!

Thanks for attention!

Comment: Have you added `end_date` to the `dates` array of the `Customer` model?

Comment: @BABAK ASHRAFI, "end_date" is attribute of the Subscription model.